# Unity3D c# check if event is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example, DelegateHandler is where I sent event

```
public class DelegateHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

     public delegate void OnButtonClickDelegate ();
     public static OnButtonClickDelegate buttonClickDelegate;

     public void OnButtonClick()
     {
     if(buttonClickDelegate!=null)
       buttonClickDelegate ();
     }

}
```

Some thread mentioned I need to assign a variable to the event before checking if it is null like :

```
    OnButtonClickDelegate tempEvent = buttonClickDelegate;
    if(tempEvent!=null)
       tempEvent();
```

This is because, in multi-thread program, we need to check if some is unsubscribed from the event between checking it is null and invoking event.
But Unity3D is single-threaded, do we also need to do this? Can I just write as

```
     if(buttonClickDelegate!=null)
       buttonClickDelegate ();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Some thread mentioned I need to assign a variable to the event before
>   checking if it is null like...
>   But Unity3D is single-threaded, do we also need to do this?

**No.**

You don't need to do that in a normal Unity app.

Now, if you start another `Thread` and you want to invoke that event from that `Thread` then yes, you do have to. If you are **not** creating another Thread, you don't need to do that.

---

Note that Unity's callback function such as [`OnAudioFilterRead`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html) is called in another Thread. If you are using this function and you want to invoke your event from there then you must assign a variable to the event before checking if it is `null`.

> But I still need to check null, right?

Yes, you should always check for `null` before calling an event.

In the new *C# 6* you could do this

```
buttonClickDelegate?.Invoke();
```

which removes the `null` check but you can't do that yet in Unity since Unity does not support *C# 6*.

Comment: My first no is a reply to *"Some thread mentioned I need to assign a variable to the event before checking if it is null"*. My second yes is a reply to if you have to check for `null` which is "yes".

Comment: Just to clarify what is already mentioned in this answer, it is possible to do the usual C# threading in Unity, and if multithreading is used that way yes you would also need to check for null.

Comment: Is it still so in 2019?